# laravel intended redirect issue when register

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to use laravel intended functionality.
What i have done is when user login it goes to the intended url,if user is not registered then it will go to the register else login page.

I cant understand where i have done something wrong

Below is my **LoginController** :

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if(!session()->has('from')){
        session()->put('from', url()->previous());
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function authenticated($request,$user)
{
    return redirect(session()->pull('from',$this->redirectTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the previous url in a session, use this;

```
return redirect()->guest('/your-login-route');
//this stores your intended route and redirects if not authenticated
```

If you are using laravel's AUTH this feature is provided out of the box.
For custom authentication, use this in your middleware's handle method like this;

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'custom-guard')
{
    if(! Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
        return redirect()->guest('/your-login-route');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

see [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware)  to create a middleware